# Django Write Authentication Redirect for Blackboxed Route URLs

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm using a django library called `django-dashing` that has a predefined set of urls that render a dashboard. I import them like this

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^dashboard/', include(dashing_router.urls)),
    ...
]
```

I want the router to be accessible only by administrators, which I can do with some config settings within `django-dashing`. However, when a non-admin user attempts to access `/dashboard/`, I want to redirect them to django's `/admin/` panel to have them log in, instead of throwing the `403` that `django-dashing` does.

Since the `django-dashing` views are effectively blackboxed, I was wondering if there was a way to write a 'pre-view' that would intercept the request to `/dashboard/`, run some code – specifically, doing the appropriate redirects – and then continue onto the actual dashboard.

I know this would be easy enough to do by writing two urls, like `/dashboard-auth/` which redirects to `/dashboard/`, but I don't want the user to have to go to one URL to get to another

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are willing to [look inside](https://github.com/talpor/django-dashing/blob/f0825c8dd0da3aae48f6924ce3b231ec7471d3fe/dashing/utils.py#L25) the 'black box' of the dashing urls, you can see that the `/dashboard/` is handled by the `Dashboard` view. You could subclass this view, and catch the `PermissionDenied` error.

```
from django.core.exceptions import PermissionDenied

from dashing.views import Dashboard

class MyDashboard(Dashboard):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return super(MyDashboard, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)
        except PermissionDenied:
            return redirect('/admin/')
```

Then add your view *above* the dashing urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^dashboard/$', MyDashboard.as_view())
    url(r'^dashboard/', include(dashing_router.urls)),
    ...
]
```

Comment: What about the other dashboard urls? They would be open to anyone

Comment: @Brobin Why do you think they would be open to anyone? I haven't removed any permission checks from the other urls, they would have the same permission checks as before.

Comment: They wouldn't be open to anyone, they'd be open to whoever you configured in the permissions in `django-dashing`'s config

Comment: I guess open to anyone was incorrect. I meant that if a user were to go to one of the `/dashboard/something` urls, they would not be redirected to the admin login like I think OP was looking for

Comment: I didn't realise people went directly to the other urls, I assumed people went to `/dashboard/` in their browser and the widgets were loaded with ajax. If you need the redirection on the widget urls as well, then a middleware or custom router would be a good approach.

Comment: I implemented this answer and it worked beautifully - thanks @Alasdair

Answer (score 3):

A Django simple custom middleware is another option...

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

class DashingRedirectMiddleware(object):

    def process_request(self, request):
        if request.path.startswith('/dashing/') and not request.user.is_staff:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('admin:login'))
        return
```

Don't forget to add this middleware to your DJANGO SETTINGS...

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    ...
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'yourapp.middleware.DashingRedirectMiddleware',
    ...
]
```

Or something like that.

Comment: Thanks, definitely the cleanest/simplest answer

Comment: You can also set up the `next` param: `'{0}?next={1}'.format(reverse('admin:login'), request.path)` so that users go to the page they were trying to reach after logging in.

Comment: The only downside with this answer is that the middleware will run on every request to any part of the site, which seems kind of overkill

Answer (score 1):

The way I would do it is by overridding dashing's default router. All of the urls are generated dynamically by the [`Router`](https://github.com/talpor/django-dashing/blob/master/dashing/utils.py) class, so by overriding the `get_urls` method, you can wrap each function in the [`staff_member_required`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/views/decorators.py#L5) decorator.

```
from django.contrib.admin.views.decorators import staff_member_required
from django.conf.urls import url

from dashing.utils import Router
from dashing.views import Dashboard


class AdminRequiredRouter(Router):

    def get_urls(self):
        urlpatterns = [
            url(r'^$', staff_member_required(Dashboard.as_view()), name='dashboard'),
        ]
        for widget, basename, parameters in self.registry:
            urlpatterns += [
                url(r'/'.join((
                    r'^widgets/{}'.format(basename),
                    r'/'.join((r'(?P<{}>{})'.format(parameter, regex)
                               for parameter, regex in parameters.items())),
                )),
                    staff_member_required(widget.as_view()),
                    name='widget_{}'.format(basename)),
            ]
        return urlpatterns

router = AdminRequiredRouter()
```

Then include your router instead of dashing's

```
from .router import router

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^dashboard/', include(router.urls)),
    ...
]
```